# How to use Function<X, Y> as Function<Object, Object> in Java?

Tags: java

(Java newbie here)
I try to implement chain of functions in Java where the input/return types are unknown. They will work so that the output of `F(n)` will feed `F(n+1)` and so on. First I need to implement `MyFunction<?, ?>` class but here starts the problem.

#### What I tried (simplified)

```java
public class MyFunction implements Function<Object, MyList<? extends Object>> {

    private final Function<Object, MyList<? extends Object>> method;

    public MyFunction(Function<Object, MyList<? extends Object>> method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public MyList<? extends Object> apply(Object input) {
        return method.apply(input);
    }

    public static MyList<String> myMethod(MyClass myClass) {
        return new MyList<String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFunction myFunction = new MyFunction(input -> myMethod(input));
        //                                              ^^^^^^^^
        //                                                  |
        //    +---------------------------------------------+
        //    |
        //    v
        //    The method myMethod(MyClass) in the type MyFunction is not  
        // applicable for the arguments (Object)
    }
}
```

As far as I know, everything is an Object in java. But here the error says different.

> The method myMethod(MyClass) in the type MyFunction is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

#### Then I tried (ignoring type-safety)

```
public class MyFunction implements Function {

    private final Function method;

    public MyFunction(Function method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public Object apply(Object input) {
        return method.apply(input);
    }

    public static MyList<String> myMethod(MyClass myClass) {
        return new MyList<String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFunction myFunction = new MyFunction(input -> myMethod(input));
    }
}
```

And the error is still the same since `apply` expects object. Because

> The type MyFunction must implement the inherited abstract method Function.apply(Object)

#### Also tried

```java
public class MyFunction implements Function<? super Object, MyList<? extends Object>>
```

This time the error is:

> A supertype may not specify any wildcard

Even when it works, I don't know how to use it in the way below.

```java
public Object apply(? super Object input)
```

#### My questions

What might be the problem? How can I pass my `Function<X, Y>` into it?

Comment: Note that as a type parameter, `? extends Object` means the same thing as just `?`.

Comment: Syntactically, your problem is that input is an Object, but myMethod expects it to by of type MyClass. So just change that parameter to Object (or implement Function<MyClass,...> instead of Function<Object,...>). However, semantically this construction seems a bit off...

Comment: `myMethod` is declared as `public static MyList<String> myMethod(MyClass myClass)` so it expects as argument instance of `MyClass`. Later you use `input -> myMethod(input)` as argument for `MyFunction(Function<Object, MyList<? extends Object>> method)` constructor. Notice that this constructor takes function from `Object -> MyList<? extends Object>>` so lambda parameter will represent `Object` type. This means your lambda `input -> myMethod(input)` is same as `(Object input) -> myMethod(input)` but as said before `myMethod` is expecting instance of `MyClass`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Notice that if you have some variable of supertype like `Person person` you could assign to it instances to some of its subtypes like `person = new TallPerson();` or `person  = new OldPerson();`. Now imagine that we have a method like `addToNBATeam(TallPerson tallPlayer)`. Should following code compile `Person somePerson = getTallOrOldPerson(); addToNBATeam(somePerson);`? No because Java can't guarantee that `person` will hold `TallPerson` which is expected by `addToNBATeam` method. Same problem is with `myMethod(input)` where type of `input` is `Object`.